# pylint import-error: Unable to import workspace modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm getting a pylint import-error (Unable to import ...) for every import instruction to a module in the same workspace. All other imports like the python environment or the installed packages work fine. It is just if I import a class from another python file in the same workspace.

For example:

```
from mymodule import MyClass
```

I tried to install a hook for pylint:

```
   "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
      "--init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append(\"${workspaceFolder}\")'"
   ]
```

Without success.

Running and debugging of the python code works. How can tell Visual Studio Code to set the right workspace-path for pylint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The pylint args should be formatted as a list:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--init-hook",
    "import sys; sys.path.append(\"${workspaceFolder}\")"
]
```